# How to fix ionic/angular page from freezing after acitivity onResume running a couple of times?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

When I push the screen lock button and the activity loses focus for the first time and I bring it back to view the activity loads up and the page is rendered correctly.

However when I try the process again it seems to stop updating the view (rendering new frames), giving the sense that the application is frozen. I can push buttons and it seems to

In the logs the only stuff that is different is as follow:
The first iteration provides:

```
18:33:58.798 3332-3419/com.app.package D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xee2c32e0: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xee231a50)
```

while the iterations thereafter do not invoke this.

I am using Ionic 4 and Angular 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this is mostly an issue on the emulator. I have seen this same behavior on some lower memory devices, and have had that confirmed via some other posting boards, although I have not found any reasonable explanation.